# Container's auto margin using Bulma

Tags: html, css, margin, bulma

### Explanation

I'm using Bulma to create a divided page with a fixed Navbar, but as you can see below, `Title 1` and `Title 2` won't line up with Navbar and `Title 3`, since the `container` left/right margin is set to auto and, therefore, goes to 0 in this first section configuration. Is there any way to achieve this using Bulma?

The problem starts happening in 1024px or higher.

### Code

I've changed the `container` background color to yellow so it's easier to see the issue.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css" />
</head>
<style>
  .container {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar is-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="columns is-vcentered is-gapless mb-0">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="hero is-fullheight is-info">
        <div class="hero-body">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title has-text-dark">
              Title 1
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="hero is-fullheight is-primary">
        <div class="hero-body">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title has-text-dark">
              Title 2
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="hero is-fullheight is-success">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title has-text-dark">
          Title 3
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```